# Какое регулярное выражение может подойти для решения этой задачи?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Какое регулярное выражение может подойти для решения этой задачи?

**Задача**: В сообщении могут содержаться IP-адреса компьютеров в формате d.d.d.d, где d - целое число из диапазона от 0 до 255. Найти все IP-адреса содержащиеся в тексте.

Comment: Что вы сами пытались сделать для решения данной задачи, что не получилось ?

Comment: мой вариант не правильно работал, теперь поняла свою ошибку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если ведущие нули **не** допустимы:
`\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\b`

Если ведущие нули допустимы:
`\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b`

Comment: 005.005.250.250 тоже находит)

Comment: [0-9] сократите \d

Comment: @Jean-Claude спасибо за замечание по поводу нулей, [0-9] сократить в \d несогласен, так в некоторых языках программирования это будет означать любую Unicode-цифру, к примеру ৯, ੧.

Comment: @Jean-Claude исправлено

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @Jean-Claude И это хорошо, что находило. теперь после исправления - хуже. Никакой стандарт не запрещает писать ведущие нули у IP. И некоторое оборудование _требует_ задавать IP с ведущими нулями !!! (в том числе в конфигах, которые потом кто нибудь захочет обрабатывать такой регуляркой)

Comment: @Mike сейчас сделаю, чтобы было две версии

Comment: @Mike ок, бум знать.